# Can I take contributions out of traditional or roth 401(k) before 59 1/2 without penalty?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, withdrawal, penalty

Can I take **contributions** out of a **traditional or roth 401(k)** before 59 1/2 without penalty?

I'm basically looking for this table and cannot find it anywhere, please let me know if any of the below is incorrect:

| --------- | Traditional 401k | Roth 401K | Traditional IRA | Roth IRA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Withdrawing Contributions before 59.5 yrs: | **No, penalty applies** | **No, penalty applies. Only earnings are penalized but contribution & earnings are lumped together here. Solution: Roll over into Roth IRA** | No, penalty applies | Yes no penalty. Must wait 5 yrs if conversion. |
| Withdrawing Earnings before 59.5 yrs: | No, penalty applies | No, penalty applies | No, penalty applies | No, penalty applies |
| Withdrawing Contributions after 59.5 yrs: | Yes no penalty, taxes apply | Yes no penalty | Yes no penalty, taxes apply | Yes no penalty |
| Withdrawing Earnings after 59.5 yrs: | Yes no penalty, taxes apply | Yes no penalty | Yes no penalty, taxes apply | Yes no penalty if account has been open for 5+ years |
| Income Limits (2024) | None | [None](https://www.schwab.com/learn/story/roth-401k-vs-roth-ira#:%7E:text=No%20income%20limits%3A%20Anyone%20can,amount%20to%20a%20Roth%20IRA.) | None | [$161,000](https://www.nerdwallet.com/article/investing/roth-ira-contribution-limits#:%7E:text=To%20contribute%20to%20a%20Roth,the%20threshold%20rises%20to%20%24240%2C000.) |

Comment: While I do not like the way the table expresses it, it does state that penalties apply to traditional 401K contributions.  Were you hoping the table was wrong?

Comment: @PeteB. yes, was looking for the correct answer in those boxes, either "Yes no penalty" or "No, penalty applies"

Comment: There are a lot of nuances. For example, contributions come out first from Roth IRAs, so you can take out contributions without taking out earnings, but you cannot take out contributions from Roth 401k without taking out earnings, though you can get around that by rolling over to Roth IRA.

Comment: For withdrawing earnings after 59.5 from Roth IRA, the "no penalty" only applies if a Roth IRA has been open for at least 5 years.

Comment: There are also non-deductible (after-tax) contributions to Traditional IRA, and after-tax contributions to Traditional 401k, which are not covered here.

Comment: Although there is no income limit to contributing to a Traditional IRA, there is an income limit to deducting a Traditional IRA contribution, if you or your spouse was covered by an employer retirement plan.

Comment: @user102008 really good info here. So you're saying "Withdrawing Contributions before 59.5 yrs / Roth 401k" should actually be "No, penalty applies?"

Comment: @user102008 Revised the relevant box to be "Yes no penalty if account has been open for 5+ years". Are there any other places in this table where its only no penalty if the account has been open for 5+ years? Perhaps "Withdrawing Contributions before 59.5 yrs / Roth 401k"?

Comment: @user102008 Awesome but sounds like the after tax Traditional IRA/401k are pretty rare, we`ll exclude those for now to keep things simple.

Comment: @user102008 I guess my question essentially boils down to: Which out of these 4 retirement products, if any, can I take my Contributions out before age 59.5 without any strings attached? (that top row). "Strings" is defined here as penalties, must wait 5 years, etc. Taxes are not strings in this case because it is expected that you pay taxes on pretax money.

Comment: I don't think "Must wait 5 yrs if rollover" is right. There is a penalty for withdrawing taxable *conversions* within 5 years of the conversion, but conversions are not contributions.

Comment: @Katsu: "So you're saying "Withdrawing Contributions before 59.5 yrs / Roth 401k" should actually be "No, penalty applies?" " No, I'm saying that "withdrawing contributions" and "withdrawing earnings" must go together, because a nonqualified distribution is prorated between contribution and earnings.

Comment: @user102008 ok thats not good. since its prorated, there will be always be a penalty. i will change it to "no, penalty applies", since the point of this exercise is to withdraw cash without penalties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot take contributions out of traditional 401(k) or IRA accounts without penalty. Since it's a pre-tax account, allowing you doing that would let you shift taxes from years of high income to years of low income. The tax deferral is only allowed without penalty if used in retirement (or, more specifically, after the age of 59 1/2).

The reason you can take out contributions without penalty from after tax and Roth accounts is that you've already paid taxes on the money when you earned it and nothing was deferred.

There are specific uses for which you can take distributions without penalty (taxes apply), for example first home purchase. The IRS actually has a [nice table here](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/retirement-topics-exceptions-to-tax-on-early-distributions).

Comment: I see, I have reflected this in the table above. Do all cells look correct to you?

Comment: For a general case, but there are some edge cases that are not reflected. For example, you cannot withdraw converted amounts from Roth IRA for 5 years even though you paid taxes on them.

Comment: Perfect I remember that. I've added it! Wish I had a beginner's guide like this that can cover 99%+ of cases but literally couldnt find it anywhere on the internet today.

Comment: @Katsu I put a linked to it in my answer. There's already a very nice table the IRS has made for you.

Comment: Hmm respectively disagree, this goes 1 level too deep. Its great for an advanced user who already knows which between the two (traditional vs. roth) is better on a "general expenses" level. For example I cant predict what type of emergency withdraw I might have 7 years from today.

Comment: it looks like the 5 year rule only applies to Earnings, not Contributions?

Comment: https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Roth_IRA#Notes

Comment: It applies to conversions (which is a contribution). Specifically, taxable conversions. The rationale is the same: prevent planned shifting of income recognition. For most people 5 years is long enough a period to not be able to plan ahead significant income change expectations.

Comment: @Katsu There are two separate 5-year rules related to Roth IRAs: one is for withdrawing conversions and the other is for withdrawing earnings. Also note [this chart](https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Roth_IRA#cite_note-23) which gives the gory details for Roth IRA distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Some plans will let you *borrow* money out of your retirement account. But that turns out not to be as attractive as it sounds; the cost is the tax-free growth that money would have returned over that period if left in the retirement account, which often works out to being more than you would have paid if you just got a bank loan. Run all the numbers rather than being distracted by the concept of "paying interest to yourself"; think of borrowing elsewhere as a possible leverage opportunity. Hold this option in reserve for emergencies.